# Excel conditional formatting with custom format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using the INDEX function to pull data from one sheet to another using a drop down data validation list to select my data set.  I have three types of data $,#, and % which I need to to format dynamically.

I have the following conditional formats in place to select custom formats depending on the item selected from the drop down list in cell F3.

- `=OR($F$3 = "Extended Sales",$F$3 = "Freight Charges",$F$3 = "Supply Cost")`
- `=OR($F$3 = "Lines Ordered",$F$3 = "DSO" =$F$3 = "Count Ship To")`
- `=OR($F$3 = "% Active Accts",$F$3 = "% of SKUs With Spend",$F$3 = "Freight as a % of Sales")`

The issue that I'm running into is that conditional formatting is getting stuck on the rule with the highest precedence.  Once I choose a data set with $ formatting all other data sets won't update to their respective format of % or #.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

You're using absolute references, change at least row references to relative:

`=OR($F3 = "Extended Sales",$F3 = "Freight Charges",$F3 = "Supply Cost")`

Comment: I tried that and the result was that my data in C8:O19 did not have any formatting applied to it.

Comment: Which column contains the condition? Please add some screenshot with sample data.